# In Excel VBA, how can I use IMPORTHTML function and increment the date in the html link

Tags: vba, excel

I am importing a lot of data into an Excel file from an HTML page that stores the data on different pages by year, with similar links, except for the year. Is it possible to write a macro with a for loop to import data from every year on one sheet, by incrementing the year in the HTML link? I am currently using:

`=IMPORTHTML("http://www.abc1900.com","table",0)`

to import the data into the excel sheet. I would like to write this:

`=IMPORTHTML("http://www.abc1900.com","table",0)`
`=IMPORTHTML("http://www.abc1901.com","table",0)`
`=IMPORTHTML("http://www.abc1902.com","table",0)`

etc. I can't quite figure it out without ruining the link. Thanks.

Comment: Is this for Google sheets?

Comment: In vba I would loop from i = 0 to 2 and have   Worksheets("Sheet" & i + 1).Range("A1").Formula = "=IMPORTHTML(""http://www.abc190" & CStr(i) & ".com" & """,""table"", 0)"   but I am not sure this function exists for VBA and Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't provide a function called `IMPORTHTML` so I assume this is a UDF.

Nevertheless with a helper column containing the numbers you can concatenate it as a string:

```
A         B      
1900      =IMPORTHTML("http://www.abc" & A:A & ".com","table",0)
=A1+1     =IMPORTHTML("http://www.abc" & A:A & ".com","table",0)
```

and copy that last row formula down.